# how to find the baseline and height of a TextView?

Tags: android, textview

TextView.getBaseline() returns -1. What is the correct way to find baseline and Height of the TextView?

Answer (score 0):

actually the layout is inflated but not yet drawn so in order to get width you will have to override the below method

```
@Override 
public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) 
{ 
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
     super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
     System.out.println("...111Height..."+textview.getMeasuredWidth()); 
}
```

Comment: Actually i want to know Baseline, top, bottom and width of each glyph in given font provided with font style and size. Can you guide me how can i do it?